# Adding additional user info into Microsoft Office templates

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office

Is there a way to add additional user address, email, phone information into MS Word and Excel for use with mail Merge or Form fill templates?

MS Word show user, user initials, and useraddress as options. unfortunately,  I also need "userphone", "useremail", and many other "userunique" fields.

I have a limited number of users, <15, so HKCU registry updates would not be a huge issue.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is add more information into the documents the users are creating like:

author, version, comments, company, tags and even custom fields. This will give you the opportunity to write the information you want.

This option is located under File > Info > Properties (located just below the preview of the doc) > Advanced properties. You have like 5 tabs in there to use.